# Using virtual inheritance on "final" classes in unfinished class hierarchies

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

Is there any harm or is it considered bad design to preemptively derive virtually classes in an unfinished class hierarchy that are currently "at the bottom" (i.e., the most derived)?  Is there a good reason one would want to wait until there was actually a need for virtual inheritance (i.e., when someone decides to extend the hierarchy and it results in a diamond)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid virtual inheritance until actually needed. When you use virtual inheritance you are leaking part of the abstractions that you build on your class, and in particular how you initialize your base class, by forcing the call to the virtual base to the most derived type.

Comment: The usual advice is to use virtual inheritance only from "pure" interfaces, usually with no user defined constructors.

Answer (score 2):

It adds complexity to a system that doesn't need it.

When you add functionality or features to a codebase in anticipation of future needs, you will often miss the target.  Sometimes that functionality will, indeed, be needed some day -- even if not today -- but in many cases it will not.  What results is large, complicated classes that are more difficult to understand, more difficult to debug, maintain and extend, and may cost more in terms of efficiency.

The [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) exists for a reason.  It keeps your code from becoming a [Rube Goldberg machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine).

Comment: virtual inheritance is complex?